# Como posicionar un Container lo mas abajo posible de un Card?

Tags: flutter, dart, card

Estoy tratando de aprender a usar mejores diseños con `Card` a lo cual e visto un que me gusto pero parece tener un tipo `Container` colocado en la parte de abajo del `Card` con un color diferente, lo que le da otro diseño

### Lo que quiero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Lo que tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente utilizando un `Positioned` pero no se mueve ni nada, igual probé metiendo el `Positioned` dentro de un `Stack` pero en ese caso simplemente de perdía el `Container`.

**Lo que tengo.**
`ListView.builder` donde se muestra el los `Card` con ayuda de un `Wrap`

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Wrap(
            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
            spacing: 10.0,
            runSpacing: 10.0,
            children: List<Widget>.generate(10, (index) => _card('produto $index',0.0,'$index descripción')),
          );
        },
      ),
```

```dart
        Widget _card(String title, double precio, String descripcion) {
        return Container(
          // margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          width: 150,
          height: 180,
          child: Card(
            color: Color(0xff00bc9b),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Producto 1',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffEDFAF8), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                ),
                ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/img/no-image.png',
                      height: 70,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    )),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 10.0,
                  child: Container(
                    // height: 55,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue/* Color(0xffEDFAF8) */, 
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(10))),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Producto de alta calidad para el consumo de todos, o solo texto largo',
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '\$4.50',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.add,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {}),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: la imagen que pusiste es como quieres que quede cierto? como te está quedando actualmente?

Comment: @diegoveloper si es como quiero que se vea, supuse que seria fácil, pero resulta que no..  edito mi pregunta para mostrar la imagen de como se ve actualmente

Comment: Abajo puse la respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te faltaba para que se pueda contraer el contenido era solo  `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` en el `Column` y bueno un `Row` .

Preparé un ejemplo para que puedas imitar la imagen que pusiste, aquí lo tienes:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GridView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2, crossAxisSpacing: 10, mainAxisSpacing: 10, childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.2),
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return _card('produto $index', 0.0, '$index descripción');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _card(String title, double price, String description) {
    return Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      color: Colors.green[100],
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(25),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Image.network(
                'https://assets.bose.com/content/dam/Bose_DAM/Web/consumer_electronics/global/products/headphones/noise_cancelling_headphones_700/product_silo_images/noise_cancelling_headphones_700_blk_EC_hero.psd/_jcr_content/renditions/cq5dam.web.320.320.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(title),
                        Text(
                          price.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edite pregunta para mostrar claramente como esta el método `_card()`

Comment: revisa mi respuesta actualizada :) , siguenos en The Dart Side en youtube y compartelo con los demás :D

Comment: Ya los estoy siguiendo, desde que hicieron su segundo directo.

Comment: que bueno, esto del diseño es solo cuestión de práctica